# How to move image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, keyboard

I want to move the board I create using left arrow to move left and right arrow to move right. But I don't know how to write left /  right arrow in syntax, so I just use 'a' and 'd' to move left and right (like in counter strike). 
Could anyone help me?
Here is my code

```
function moveObj(name, Xpix) 
{    
    obj = document.getElementById(name);

    px = parseInt(obj.style.left) + Xpix;       
    obj.style.left = px;
}

function ProcessKeypress(e)
{
    var myObj = "pantul";
    var moveBy = 10;
    obj = document.getElementById(myObj);
    x=parseInt(obj.style.left);

    if (e.keyCode) keycode=e.keyCode;
    else keycode=e.which;
    ch=String.fromCharCode(keycode);

    if(x > 220 || x <720)
    {
        if(ch=='a')         moveObj(myObj, -moveBy);
        else if(ch=='d')    moveObj(myObj, moveBy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Character codes:

37 - left

38 - up

39 - right

40 - down
```

so you can use keycode(not char),

```
function ProcessKeypress(e)
{
    var myObj = "pantul";
    var moveBy = 10;
    obj = document.getElementById(myObj);
    x=parseInt(obj.style.left);

    if (e.keyCode) keycode=e.keyCode;
    else keycode=e.which;

    if(x > 220 || x <720)
    {
        if(keycode == 37)         moveObj(myObj, -moveBy);
        else if(keycode == 39)    moveObj(myObj, moveBy);
    }
}
```